# Product as batch of items (but items are all the same) and solidus_product_assembly

Tags: product, solidus, option-type

I am using Solidus for an e-shop application, and I am trying to handle products that are sold as packs of items. I have a Product "Piece of paper" with a stock count value, and I am only selling those pieces of paper by 50.

The item "Piece of paper" is stored individually in my stock location, but never sold individually.

I have two possible solutions in mind:

1. I have seen I can create an OptionType "Pack", assign it to my product and then create a variant with the option type value set to 50. But I did not find any way to link the stock count of my individual pieces of paper with the stock count of my 50 items packs, which is what I want to do.
2. I tried the solidus_product_assembly add-on which enables products as batch of other products. This solution seems to be working better as it handles the stock update of assembly_parts of the product. My problem here is with the stock of my assembly product : it seems to me I have to set it by hand, no automatic calcul is done here depending on availability of composing other products. Maybe I missed something ? For the moment I override the total_on_hand Spree::Product's method to handle that, among few other customizations.

Since in my case I won't ever have more than one assembly_part in an assembly product, does anyone think of a better solution, or is it as I think the most obvious way to handle that?

Answer (score 0):

We have a similar kind of situation. We have made setsize associated with a product. In front-end code we do display the set size and take quantity as set quantity. The price we show os for individual item, you can show it for the whole set as per your requirement. During order placement just multiple the set value with the ordered quantity. You'll need to add some JavaScript code and overrider a bit of controller code from the front-end gem to get proper quantity in terms of set. Also wherever you are displaying the quantity to the end-user keep that updated in terms of set. Also just another tip, from the backend the order can be modified and if quantity is changed to some value not divisible by set size than display the quantity in terms of items.

On the backend you may let the quantity be in terms of items only. I would suggest not to tweak anything else to keep rest of the code upgradable and stable enough.